# Comparar duas listas de objetos e pegar apenas os diferentes

Tags: c#, .net, lista, linq

Estou com problemas para comparar duas listas do mesmo tipo `List<Produto>` na minha classe produto tenho a seguinte estrutura.

```
public class Product
    {
        public int IdProduct { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public Supplier supplier { get; set; }

        public Product(){}
    }
```

E na minha classe de `Supplier` tenho:

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int IdSupplier { get; set; }
    public string Main { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

E eu gero uma lista inicial, e uma final. A final contem mais elementos de produtos.

#### Teste

```
List<Product> listaProdutosDiferentes = listaPrincipalProdutos.Union(listaFinalProdutos).ToList();
```

Porem esse teste apenas concatenou as duas listas e não pegando formando uma lista com produtos diferentes do outro.

#### Edição

Eu tenho duas listas, a primeira tem alguns produtos podendo ser
(id;nome)
1, Celular Motorola One;
2, Celular Motorola G6;
3, Celular Motorola E5;

Na minha segunda lista terá a mesma lista da primeira (Não necessariamente seguindo uma sequência).

5, Celular Samsung Galaxy;
1, Celular Motorola One;
2, Celular Motorola G6;
3, Celular Motorola E5;
4, Celular Iphone 6S;

A minha lista final precisa ser

1, Celular Motorola One;
2, Celular Motorola G6;
3, Celular Motorola E5;
4, Celular Iphone 6S;
5, Celular Samsung Galaxy;

Por que faço isso? pra que quando uma pessoa for fazer uma busca no meu sistema, o sistema apresente primeiro a pesquisa que o cliente fez, exemplo "Celular Motorola", e depois os outros itens que tem um relacionamento, nesse caso outros celulares.

#### [Duplicada]

Marcaram como duplicada, porem na resposta que deixaram não resolveu meu problema eu fiz os códigos proposto, porem todos não excluem o item que já tem na outra lista, vou mostrar pela imagens:
[image: IDE mostrando execução]

Aqui tem 4 produtos.

[image: IDE mostrando execução]

Aqui tem 9 produtos

[image: IDE mostrando execução]

E na minha lista que deveria ser a lista diferente contem 9 produtos e não 5

Comment: O que esse `Supplier` tem a ver com o problema?

Comment: Só gerei o que eu tenho, pois não sabia se ele poderia influenciar no resultado

Comment: Não esqueça que a classe Product deve prover uma implementação própria dos métodos GetHashCode() e Equals(). Ou use, no método Except(), um "comparador de Products" que implemente a interface IEqualityComparer<T>

Comment: @LeandroPenhalver A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: @Maniero olha cara, eu não consegui fazer como vocês fizeram a proposta, ai então eu fiz como deu, joguei isso pra tratar no sql

Answer (score 3):

Você deve usar o [`Except()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads) do LINQ, o que uso junta as listas sem distinguir o que já está na outra.

```
var listaProdutosDiferentes = listaPrincipalProdutos.Except(listaFinalProdutos);
```

Por outro lado pode ser que queira isto (não tenho como afirmar, a pergunta é um pouco ambígua, veja qual produz o resultado que espera):

```
var listaProdutosDiferentes = listaPrincipalProdutos.Except(listaFinalProdutos).Concat(listaFinalProdutos.Except(listaPrincipalProdutos));
```

Ou ainda usar o [`Intersect()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
var listaProdutosDiferentes = listaPrincipalProdutos.Intersect(listaFinalProdutos);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Except2.cs).

Outro ponto é que só deve usar `ToList()` quando realmente precisa concretizar a lista, pode até ser que seja o seu caso, não tenho como contestar isso, mas pode ser que não precise, então preferi não usar.

Comment: Então, eu preciso que seja uma lista, por que eu ao final do código eu retorno uma lista do tipo produto.

Comment: O código que você fez ali em cima não funcionou, eu preciso comparar as duas listas e depois preciso que esse LINQ me retorne apenas os produtos que não tem na primeira lista.

Comment: Quase sempre as pessoas acham que precisam converter el lista e não precisam, muitas vezes o erro está na API criada. Mas eu não tenho com afirmar neste caso porque não tem informação sobre. Eu dei mais uma opção, se nada disso resolver a pergunta não está clara mesmo.

Comment: Maniero, eu adicionei a pergunta uns resultados para explicar melhor o que eu quero e o motivo de estar tentando fazer dessa forma, caso tenha outra forma de resolver se não no linq não tem problema também.